# Get style and script file versions and use them while writing a cache manifest file

Tags: javascript

Earlier I've learned how to remove file versions from wordpress style and script file source links inside the `wp_head` function. From here: [How to remove file versions from the file source links in wp_head?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/96324/how-to-remove-file-versions-from-the-file-source-links-in-wp-head/)

I had a good reason needing that action. Why? While writing a cache manifest file, inside that file I managed to write also absolute source links, but without `?ver=` parameter. `wp_head` has generated the used theme with `?ver=` parameter the syle and script file inclusions. So there was smooth differences between the cache data and theme data. I don't know if that was the reason not getting the styles while being offline my test site.

**Question:**

Now what I'd like to know, is the way how can I add `?ver=` parameter to the cache manifest file entries. I'm writing this way the cache file's lines:

```
$hashes = "";
$network = array("\n\nNETWORK:");
$cache = array("\n\nCACHE:");
$path = get_stylesheet_directory()."/";
$dir = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator( $path );

foreach(new RecursiveIteratorIterator($dir) as $file) {
    if ($file->IsFile() && $file != "./manifest.php" && substr($file->getFilename(), 0, 1) != ".") {
        if(preg_match('/.php$/', $file)) {
            if (isAllowedExtension($file))
                array_push($network,"\n" . str_replace($path, './', $file));
        } else {
            if (isAllowedExtension($file))
                array_push($cache,"\n" . str_replace($path, './', $file));
        }

        $hashes .= md5_file($file);
    }
}
```

Hence this aren't absolute url's, I'm just curious how could be possible adding the `?ver=` parameter to this file url's? :)

===

Update:

```
if( !strpos( $file, '?ver=' ) ) {
    $file = add_query_arg( 'ver', $file );
    return $file;
}
```

This is only a try... Not complete code. First I think we should check if the file has any version, then add the version parameter after the source url.

Answer (score 0):

You *could* use `add_query_arg()`:

```
$url = add_query_arg( 'ver', $GLOBALS['wp_version'], $url );
```

But I see one problem: How can you be sure the resource is actually used? And how do you know the author has not passed a custom version?

So you can do that only in a very controlled environment: when you know everything about the code.

Comment: Yes, you're right. The above code is implemented in a function which is runned within the next actions: `save_post`, `switch_theme`, `register_activation_hook`. If the site administrator would upload a new versioned stylesheet for example, he will need to deactivate and activate again the plugin. I would not use a cronjob and don't see another dynamicaly way to control this versioning issue. BTW, your code works like a charm integrated into my example. Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: Oh, i did a mistake. After each every file is added the `?ver=3.5.1` Hehe. Which is wrong. I think that is the wp version instead of the required versions.