# Linking wp_enqueue can't find the javascript file (adds "?ver=x.x.x" to the src)

Tags: javascript, wp-enqueue-script

So I'm trying to link in a javascript file the right way, by using this:

```
--functions.php--
function custom_scripts() {
    wp_register_script('myscript','/backdrop.js',array('jquery'));
    wp_enqueue_script('myscript'); 
    console.log("test - inside custom_scripts"); 
}
add_action( 'wp_print_scripts', 'custom_scripts');
```

I don't see the console logs in the chrome console window, and I'm not sure if I should see them or not. However I see that one of my files cannot be found: `/backdrop.js?ver=3.5.1`. 
The directory is correct but the `?ver=3.5.1` obviously doesn't match up. Since I'm manually registering the script in a custom `functions.php`, why does it still do this?

Comment: where is your script exactly? in your theme directory, or the root of your domain?

Answer (score 1):

`console.log()` is a JavaScript function. You cannot use it in PHP. Add that to your JavaScripts.

The version parameter should not affect the file access. But you can [remove that parameter](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/96325/73) and see if it works then. If it does, your server configuration needs further inspection, because it should also work with the version.

Comment: Oh lol, that's what you get when you are learning 2 languages simultaneously >_> And wow, that did the trick. thank you!