# How to add GET variable after script url?

Tags: scripts, wp-register-script

So, I've registered and enqueued my script.

`http://mysite.com/wp-content/plugins/my-plugin/script.js?ver=3.6`

But how do I add a GET variable on the script src url?

`http://mysite.com/wp-content/plugins/my-plugin/script.js?ver=3.6&myVar=whatever`

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Filter [`script_loader_src`](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/96325/73) and use `add_query_arg()`. You can use [`parse_url()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) or the second argument `$handle` to target specific scripts...

I have included multiple redundant options here:

```
add_filter( 'script_loader_src', 'wpse_99842_add_get_var_to_url', 10, 2 );

function wpse_99842_add_get_var_to_url( $url, $handle )
{
    if ( 'my_handle' !== $handle )
        return $url;

    if ( empty ( $_GET['myvar'] ) )
        return $url;

    $parts = parse_url( $url );

    // specific host
    if ( 'example.com' !== $parts['host'] )
        return $url;

    // specific path
    if ( '/foo/bar' !== $parts['path'] )
        return $url;

    // or specific start of path
    if ( 0 !== strpos( $parts['path'], '/foo/' ) )
        return $url;

    return add_query_arg( 'myVar', $_GET['myvar'], $url );
}
```