# Speed optimization on WP site, Remove query strings from static resources

Tags: performance

I am using GTMetrix to test the speed of one of my sites. The report says that I should 'Remove query strings from static resources'

Resources with a "?" in the URL are not cached by some proxy caching servers. Remove the query string and encode the parameters into the URL for the following resources...

How can I do that and is it recommended?

Comment: Have you seen [How to remove file versions from the file source links in wp_head?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/96324/73)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMO it is recommended to ignore 50% of the google speedtest recommendations, this is one of them

> Resources with a "?" in the URL are not cached by some proxy caching
>   servers. Remove the query string and encode the parameters into the
>   URL for the following resources...

Maybe it was true in 2005 but now I wish google would have specified exactly which are they. In any case the chances of any page of any small or medium site to be cached and reused from the cache is minimal. The effort you might need to put in rearranging the urls of your static resources is not worth the zero speed improvement your site will gain.

Comment: I would advise against blanket statement in regards to performance. Web is not identical for everyone - someone is behind corporate proxy, someone is on mobile behind traffic optimizer, etc. Bash google's recommendation when you have _proof_ they are harmful. :)

Comment: I qualified it to "small and medium sites", how many people in your organization read my (currently broken) blog? ;)

Comment: @rarst, this is not a duplicate as this is a more general question. you can't remove ? from static resources which weren't enqueued

Comment: Which is explicitly mentioned in that thread. :)

Comment: I guess the most important question is whether I will see any speed improvements by doing this? If not I'd gladly leave things as they are.

Comment: As @Rarst say you might be in a unique position in which it will make a difference but I believe the chances for that if you are not working on a big portal is very slim. Not being able to actually test the results of such recommendation is part of why I don't like it.